# GPIO.read() not working in mongoose os (mos tool)

Tags: mongoose-os

I am using ESP32. I am working with inbuilt led on GPIO 2. I want to read the level of pin.

```
let led = 2;
GPIO.set_mode(led, GPIO.MODE_OUTPUT);
GPIO.write(led, 0);
Timer.set(1000, true, function(){
print(GPIO.read(led)==0);
 if (GPIO.read(led)==0){
GPIO.write(led, 0);
 }
else{
GPIO.write(led, 1);
 }}, null);
```

the print statement only printing ‘0’ on console although led light is on.
 what’s wrong with code and why GPIO.read() not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gpio.read() canno read state of output pin hence

I solve this issue by importing a c function from "mgos_gpio.h" in init.js.
in main.c, imported "mgos_gpio.h" and in init.js file, I use below code-

```
let readPinVal = ffi('bool mgos_gpio_read_out(int)');
let pinStatus = readPinVal(pinNo);
```